# How to transparency border color for tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor, cgcolor

I have successfully changed the color of my `UIButton` using alpha, but when I try to do the same for my tableview it doesn't work.

```
_tablemenu.layer.borderWidth = 2;
_tableview.layer.borderWidth = 5;
_tableview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xCC green:0xFF blue:0x99 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
_tablemenu.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

The code is working fine for _tablemenu,but when i try to initialize a `UIColor` with RGB values it doesn't work.

Comment: `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` expects values between 0 and 1. So divide the value by 255.

Comment: @Larme ok i will try it ...

Comment: are you try for your tableview or tableview cell bro..?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik uitableview bro ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to give value between 0 to 1 in R,G and B

```
_tableview.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
```

Comment: then how its accepted for my uibutton bro @techloverr

Comment: paste code here please you might be using native colors

Comment: good then approve as right and upvote so that everyone can use it

Comment: i tried to accept but its giving message to wait for 5 minutes to accept answer

Comment: _btnwelcome.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0xCC green:0xFF blue:0x99 alpha:0.5]; bro this is my code for uibutton

Comment: ok try after 5 minutes.. this should not work,too may be CGColor is the issue

Comment: bro thaks for your suggestion :)

Comment: @KishoreKumar any time :)

Answer (score 0):

what i have found truly to be transparent are the following `RBG` values,

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:181/255.f green:191/255.f blue:208/255.f alpha:0].CGColor;
```